# Save a users HTML in txt file for display later

Tags: php, html

**Brief outline:** Looking to save a customers custom build (html) and save as a text file on server. When they return, the PHP page will display their HTML.

**Problems:** I'm thinking their may be a HUGE vulnerability in saving a block of html (in txt file) server side. I've tested my builder, and if I hit save button, it saves HTML I input through FireBug.

**Question:** What are best practices for saving a customers block of HTML without risk / injection? Is `file_get_contents` for displaying the HTML not a good idea?

Comment: Saving a html tree on the server side is not a security issue in itself, regardless of whether you save to a file or, more common, to a database. Displaying such user input can be a _huge_ security issue, you have to sanitize the input. Take a look at `tidyhtml` or similar solutions: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ Yes, that means you modify the user input.

Comment: Sorry, a correction to my comment above: displaying such user specified html is only a security issue if you present it to _other_ users. If a user breaks or corrupts his own view, then it is the problem of the user. He can do so anyway using the browser builtin development console.

Comment: Hey arkascha, thank you for the response.  The reason I didn't save to DB is it's a big block of HTML.  The HTML will only be visible to the user unless he shares his "custom build" with another user by URL.  (Uses URL parameters to pull a specific "build").  Am I correct in assuming that file_get_contents won't run PHP since it's basically "text" at that point?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand _why_ you do not save that html to a database. That is much faster, much easier to maintain and offers much better portability. You are right to assume that functions like `file_get_contents()` do _not_ interpret any contained script elements (unlike `include()` and `require()`, which _do_). But that is not the point. The security issue comes up if other users receive such html snippets which are then rendered in their browser. Especially contained javascript or embedded images can be used to forget requests on behalf of that other user. Do not allow that!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use htmlentities function to store the template
cf : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php

Did it helped you ?